# Testing request after request jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a quick question I have a simple web application composed of cars a user is able to select the car and then is displayed his choice. The application is a dynamic web application built in eclipse. 
So I am testing my web application using jmeter.

Firstly the user searches for a car ..... this works in jmeter
The result page has a checkbox with select car, the user checks the box and the cars are selected... this does not work.

THe thing is after the user selects the cars his selection is shown the thing is how do I test generate proper Http request for this because the each of these request share data amongst each other and cannot be tested indvidaully. I am using a simple controller in jmetter and I have grouped these http requests

So it looks like this

```
Simple Controller
  Search Cars  (Get Method ) ... Works
  Search Results .. works 
  Select Car (Get Method)... Does not wrok
  Selected Cars ... Does not work
```

I am new to jmeter

Comment: Please share error or request-response for Select Car.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go though the below link, it will help you to record and replay the scenarios using Jmeter
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

- first you can record the scenario
- second apply correlation where ever required
- group the scenarios together using controllers (simple/transaction... etc.)

re-run the script

Hope this will help